# How to use memcache in dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to use Memcache in dafalow ParDo? any ideas how?I can't use existing memcahse lib as they belong to appengine and are not serializable.
Rohit

Comment: ParDo's can execute arbitrary code, you're free to use any libraries you want, including libraries for Memcache access. Can you give an example of the code you're using and the errors you're getting?

Comment: I am trying to use the API's listed in the servlet in the pasted link below to access memcache.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/examples . I am using this inside ParDo. It throws java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)

Answer (score 9):

My guess is, you have a private variable in your `DoFn` of type `MemcacheServiceImpl` (if my guess is wrong, please edit your question to include the code of your `DoFn`).

Indeed, Dataflow serializes your `DoFn`'s when you submit the pipeline and de-serializes them on the workers. The proper way to handle this is to make the variable transient, and initialize it lazily:

```
class MyDoFn extends DoFn<..., ...> {
  private transient MemcacheService memcache;
  private MemcacheService getMemcache() {
    if (memcache == null) {
      memcache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
      ...
    }
  }

  public void process(...) {
    ...use getMemcache()...
  }
}
```

Also note that  to access AppEngine APIs, including Memcache, from a non-AppEngine environment, you should use the [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi).

Comment: Is there any chance I could make something similar work with the python SDK ?

Comment: @jkff I am getting _Can't make API call memcache.Get in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager_ exception when I run my Dataflow Job can you please help me to troubleshoot? Do I need to user RemoteAPI? Can you please provide some examle of using Memcache in Dataflow.