# Use Memcache in Dataflow: NullPointerException at NamespaceManager.get

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to access GAE Memcache and Datastore APIs from Dataflow.
I have followed [How to use memcache in dataflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709762/how-to-use-memcache-in-dataflow) and setup Remote API https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi

In my pipeline I have written

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    RemoteApiOptions remApiOpts = new RemoteApiOptions()
            .server("xxx.appspot.com", 443)
            .useApplicationDefaultCredential();
    RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
    installer.install(remApiOpts);

    try {
        DatastoreConfigManager2.registerConfig("myconfig");
        final String topic = DatastoreConfigManager2.getString("pubsub.topic");
        final String stagingDir = DatastoreConfigManager2.getString("dataflow.staging");

        ...

        bqRows.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                .named("Insert row")
                .to(new SerializableFunction<BoundedWindow, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(BoundedWindow window) {
                        // The cast below is safe because CalendarWindows.days(1) produces IntervalWindows.
                        IntervalWindow day = (IntervalWindow) window;

                        String dataset = DatastoreConfigManager2.getString("dataflow.bigquery.dataset");
                        String tablePrefix = DatastoreConfigManager2.getString("dataflow.bigquery.tablenametemplate");

                        String dayString = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
                                .print(day.start());
                        String tableName = dataset + "." + tablePrefix + dayString;
                        LOG.info("Writing to BigQuery " + tableName);
                        return tableName;
                    }
                })
```

where DatastoreConfigManager2 is

```
public class DatastoreConfigManager2 {

private static final DatastoreService DATASTORE = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
private static final MemcacheService MEMCACHE = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();

static {
    MEMCACHE.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandlers.getConsistentLogAndContinue(Level.INFO));
}

private static Set<String> configs = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();

public static void registerConfig(String name) {
    configs.add(name);
}

private static class DatastoreCallbacks {
    // https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/callbacks
    @PostPut
    public void updateCacheOnPut(PutContext context) {
        Entity entity = context.getCurrentElement();
        if (configs.contains(entity.getKind())) {
            String id = (String) entity.getProperty("id");
            String value = (String) entity.getProperty("value");
            MEMCACHE.put(id, value);
        }
    }
}

private static String lookup(String id) {
    String value = (String) MEMCACHE.get(id);
    if (value != null) return value;
    else {
        for (String config : configs) {
            try {
                PreparedQuery pq = DATASTORE.prepare(new Query(config)
                        .setFilter(new FilterPredicate("id", FilterOperator.EQUAL, id)));
                for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable()) {
                    value = (String) entity.getProperty("value"); // use last
                }
                if (value != null) MEMCACHE.put(id, value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}

public static String getString(String id) {
    return lookup(id);
}
```

}

When my pipeline runs on Dataflow I get the exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.appengine.api.NamespaceManager.get(NamespaceManager.java:101)
at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.BaseMemcacheServiceImpl.getEffectiveNamespace(BaseMemcacheServiceImpl.java:65)
at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.doGet(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:401)
at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.get(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:412)
at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:49)
at my.training.google.common.config.DatastoreConfigManager2.lookup(DatastoreConfigManager2.java:80)
at my.training.google.common.config.DatastoreConfigManager2.getString(DatastoreConfigManager2.java:117)
at my.training.google.mss.pipeline.InsertIntoBqWithCalendarWindow$1.apply(InsertIntoBqWithCalendarWindow.java:101)
at my.training.google.mss.pipeline.InsertIntoBqWithCalendarWindow$1.apply(InsertIntoBqWithCalendarWindow.java:95)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Write$Bound$TranslateTableSpecFunction.apply(BigQueryIO.java:1496)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$Write$Bound$TranslateTableSpecFunction.apply(BigQueryIO.java:1486)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$TagWithUniqueIdsAndTable.tableSpecFromWindow(BigQueryIO.java:2641)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$TagWithUniqueIdsAndTable.processElement(BigQueryIO.java:2618)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** my functional requirement is building a pipeline with some configurable steps based on datastore entries.

Comment: Have you considered using DatastoreIO or Cloud Datastore API instead, and another type of cache like a memcached or redis on Cloud Launcher? I would try to avoid using remote API if possible, it looks like a bit of a hack using it from Dataflow...

Comment: This looks like it is either a misconfiguration of Memcache, or you're passing in a null `String id` to the `lookup` method. Can you add a check for that case?

Comment: Also note that the line `DatastoreConfigManager2.registerConfig("myconfig");` will not be executed on the workers, so the configuration will not be included in `DatastoreConfigManager2` that you're interacting with inside of the `DoFn`.